# "Invalid column name" MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Eu tenho uma tabela em um `DbContext`, troco o nome dela, atualizo a `database` e quando eu executo eu sou redirecionado para o Visual Studio com a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Invalid column name 'SetorId'.

**Obs:**O nome da tabela está Setor_Id. Eu mudo o nome no `model` e na própria table antes de atualizar a `database`.

**Model:**

```
public class RamalModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome é obrigatório.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O número é obrigatório.")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Setor")]
    public int SetorId { get; set; }

    public Setor Setor { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext:**

```
public class RamaDb : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Usuario> Usuarios { get; set; }

    public DbSet<RamalModel> Ramais { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Setor> Setores { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Area> Areas { get; set; }
}
```

**Table:**

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RamalModels] (
[ID]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Nome]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
[Numero]   INT            NOT NULL,
[Setor_Id] INT            DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.RamalModels] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_SetorId]
ON [dbo].[RamalModels]([Setor_Id] ASC);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O nome da coluna em banco está errado. Deveria ser `SetorId`, e não `Setor_Id`. Não use *underscore* para mapear suas chaves de entidades, pois eles não fazem parte da convenção do Entity Framework.

Você está usando o Entity Framework errado. É ele que deveria atualizar o banco automaticamente pra você, e não você atualizar o banco com scripts.